# Run a formula only if the contents of a column are above a certain date

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm creating a pipeline tool for work that requires data entered into various cells of a table. The formula below is being used to figure our the conversion rate of sales but I also want to add to this formula only when the contents of tbl_Deals_1[Exp. Settlement Date] is greater than the 1st of October 2017.

`=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(--(Tbl_Deals_1[Sales Phase]="Won"),--(Tbl_Deals_1[Exp. Settlement Date]>Data!B1),Tbl_Deals_1[Exp. Settlement Date]-Tbl_Deals_1[Date Entered]+1)/COUNTIF(Tbl_Deals_1[Sales Phase],"Won"),"")`

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by “… I also want to add to this formula only when …”?

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure what you mean
by “… I also want to add to this formula only when …”. 
If you simply want to *display* this formula’s computed value
only under that condition,

```
=IF(tbl_Deals_1[Exp. Settlement Date]>DATE(2017,10,1), <your_formula_(above), <null_value>)
```

will do that. 
*`<null_value>`* can be `""`, `0`,
or whatever you want displayed for dates before October.

Comment: Thanks Scott - so I put this in:

=IF(tbl_Deals_1[Exp. Settlement Date]>Data!B1, IFERROR((COUNTIF(Tbl_Deals_1[Sales Phase],"WON")/SUM(COUNTIF(Tbl_Deals_1[Sales Phase],"WON"),COUNTIF(Tbl_Deals_1[Sales Phase],"LOST"))),""), ""

and am getting an error "Your formula is missing a parenthesis--) or Check formula and add parenthesis in appropriate place.  ??

Comment: In case you don’t understand what (I guess) just happened: comments can’t be multi-line. If you’re trying to say something to clarify the question, edit the question; don’t try to do it in comments.

Comment: Seriously?  You’re trying to call a function without a `)` at the end?  And you can’t figure out how to fix it when Excel tells you exactly what went wrong?

Comment: Sorry Scott - I'm new to this trying to waddle my way through and do something to help someone out. Appreciate your help til now. I'll keep ploughing through.....